# Segmentation fault on assigning empty string

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

Here is the code which I am trying to run -

```
typedef struct node{
  string str;
}node;

string s = "";

node *t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
t->str = s ; // if s is empty, this statement gives segmentation fault.

cout<<t->str<<endl;
```

Comment: Pick a book from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Looks like a case of learning `C` instead of `C++`.  The `typedef struct` is an indication of this.  In `C++`, there is no need for `typedef struct`, just `struct node { string str; };`, and using `malloc` was covered in the answer below.

Comment: Eeeek, that looks more like C compiled with a C++ compiler than proper C++. Don't use `malloc` and break out of that `typedef struct` habit.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ you should *never* use `malloc` to allocate objects with constructors. The `malloc` function only allocates memory, but it doesn't cause the constructors to be called.

That means your `str` member is *uninitialized* and you have *undefined behavior* when using it.

***If*** you really need to allocate dynamically use `new` instead:

```
node* t = new node;
```